# Can't update Composer

Tags: composer-php

This is the error I get when I run `composer update` on my remote server:

[image]
I have tried raising the memory_limit to 1G. That doesn't work.

I actually do have swap (so I'm not sure why the error is saying I don't).

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:           495        247        248          0         12         48
-/+ buffers/cache:        187        308
Swap:         1023        204        819
```

I'm really not sure what else to try...

If anyone has any suggestions I would certainly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A memory of "495M" is an indicator of a cheap VPS box.
Your are trying to run Composer on a production box, i guess.
And you are updating your packages, including the development packages: `require-dev`.

(A) I doubt that you want to do your development on a machine, which such harsh constraints, but anyway, here are some pointers:

- reduce the workload for Composer's solver by defining exact versions, instead of relying on additional operators, like tilde `~` or wildcard `*`. For example: don't use `1.2.*` or `~1.2`, when there is a `1.2.3`.
- skip installing packages listed in require-dev `composer update --no-dev`, you don't need them on a production box
- excute composer in verbose mode, to find out how much more memory you would need ;)

But don't be surprised, when it still doesn't work.

(B) To really solve the issue, you might properly package your project on a development machine. Just run `composer install --no-dev` or `composer update --no-dev` on the dev machine and package your project folder, then deploy it to production (copy file, extract).

(C) Run `update` locally, push the `composer.lock` file to Github and then pull it on the production server, then run `install`. By doing that, the already resolved versions from the lock file are used, lowering the work and memory usage.

In short:

- build a release on the dev box, then deploy to production
- this avoids executing Composer on the machine with constraints

Comment: `~4.1.*` is a invalid version constraint. It should be `~4.1` and `4.1.*`

Comment: Thank you. Running `update` locally, pushing the composer.lock file to Github and then pulling it on the server, then running `install` did the trick :)